# Python Tkinter Browsing a File- Issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am experiencing some issues when displaying the location of the image selected. Is there a reason why it displays `<_io.TextIOWrapper name =`along with `mode='r'encoding ='cp1252>`? I just want it to display the location of the image along with the name of the image not those extra stuff. Is there something that I am doing that is causing this to occur? Please advise.

```
def button(self):
    self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Upload Image", command = self.fileDialog)
    self.button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)     


def fileDialog(self):
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File", filetype = (("jpeg", "*.jpg"), ("All files", "*.")))
    self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
    self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
    self.label.configure(text = self.filename)
```

[image: Image display]

Comment: It sounds like you're using `getopenfile` rather than `getopenfilename` (or the "save" variant).  Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates the problem. This example shouldn't take more than a dozen lines or so, max.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to include a snippet of the code. Please see modified question. @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filedialog.askopenfile` gives file object, not file name.

You have to display `self.filename.name` instead of `self.filename`

---

Full working example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

file_object = filedialog.askopenfile(title="Select file")
print('file_object:', file_object)
print('file_object.name:', file_object.name)
#data = file_object.read()

label = tk.Label(root, text=file_object.name)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Or use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile` and you get file name.

---

Full working example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file")
print('filename:', filename)
#data = open(filename).read()

label = tk.Label(root, text=filename)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```